# Cloud Camera for iPhone

Tags: video

I'm looking for an easy way to create a video/audio/text diary. The problem so far is that almost no app uploads the video to a cloud service like Evernote (would be my preferred option) and delete the video locally. This is in terms of capturing apps.
On the diary side. Almost all diary apps want to have all of their content locally as well as in the cloud. This means unnecessary wasted space.

1 Second Everyday promised to work on this feature ever since its introduction, but they never delivered. Also the videos need to be one second short. I'd prefer to record video at any length.

There was one app that uploads directly to the cloud, but I forgot its name.

Anything that would help me make a cloud-based video/audio diary would help. Thank you!